# How to apply CSS by URL Parameters? Hide div by URL

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, parameters

How can I hide a div by ID / Class using a parameter in the URL?

For example site.com/?divID=hide

Or disable a specific CSS to act another.  But it had to be through the URL: /

Comment: You can do by ajax i suppose. Anyway since you are new, let me tell you that Stackoverflow is not a place to ask "how to do this feature?" but rather "I am trying to do this feature, but it's not working, how to solve it?" kind of site. And welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getParams = function() {
    var url = window.location
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params
}

var urlParams= getParams();
```

You will get URL params in "urlParams" object and use that "urlParams[divID]" to get the details of URL params and apply CSS using jQuery/js .

Here is the syntax of jQuery to apply CSS

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Here is the syntax of js to apply CSS

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can hide any element you want by giving it the `hidden` parameter.

```
    <div class="container" hidden> *content* </div>
```

This will hide the div and it's content.
If you wanted to do it using PHP, you could do the following: (assuming your URL is `site.com?hide`)

```
<?php
$hide = isset($_GET['hide']); //this returns a boolean value
?>

<body>
    <div <?= $hide ? "hidden":""?> > *content* </div>
</body>
```

What `<?= $hide ? "hidden":""?>` does is basically, if the GET parameter `hide` is set, will print in your HTML (inside your div tag) the word 'hidden', which will make your div invisible.